# Синтаксическая роль словосочетания

Tags: синтаксис, морфология

Скажите, пожалуйста, в предложении "В организме человека насчитывается  около двухсот типов различных клеток" какую синтаксическую роль будет выполнять словосочетание "двухсот типов". Я думаю, что оно является дополнением (Р. п. количественного числительного), а само предложение - односоставным безличным. Ответьте, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В организме человека насчитывается около двухсот типов различных
> клеток.

Предложение **двусоставное**.

Количественно-именное словосочетание *двести типов* в сочетании с наречием *около* является синтаксически нечленимым: ***около двухсот типов** (клеток).*

В рассматриваемом предложении является **подлежащим**.

**Сказуемое — *насчитывается.***

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.